# I have integrate cybersource payment gateway in ruby but i want integrate with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

cybersource payment gateway integrate with ruby is working fine. But I want to integrate with ruby on rails. Is it possible to integrate with ruby on rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Class: ActiveMerchant::Billing::CyberSourceGateway`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Shopify/active_merchant/ActiveMerchant/Billing/CyberSourceGateway) of [active_merchant](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant)

Example

```
require 'active_merchant'

# Use the TrustCommerce test servers
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test

gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CyberSourceGateway.new(
            :login => 'TestMerchant',
            :password => 'password')

# ActiveMerchant accepts all amounts as Integer values in cents
amount = 1000  # $10.00

# The card verification value is also known as CVV2, CVC2, or CID
credit_card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
                :first_name         => 'Bob',
                :last_name          => 'Bobsen',
                :number             => '4242424242424242',
                :month              => '8',
                :year               => Time.now.year+1,
                :verification_value => '000')

# Validating the card automatically detects the card type
if credit_card.validate.empty?
  # Capture $10 from the credit card
  response = gateway.purchase(amount, credit_card)

  if response.success?
    puts "Successfully charged $#{sprintf("%.2f", amount / 100)} to the credit card #{credit_card.display_number}"
  else
    raise StandardError, response.message
  end
end
```